# Variable-parameters array empty in Unity C#

Tags: c#, mono

In a script in C# running under Unity3D, I have defined a trivial function using variable parameters.

```
void foo(string bar, params string[] baz) {
    Debug.Log(baz.Length);
}
```

I then use the function later in my code,

```
foo("abc", "def", "ghi");
```

However, rather than having 2 returned (as there should be two additional parameters), `baz` has 0 elements.

What am I missing? Furthermore, this is used in a large-ish application, so what other code could be affecting this?

Comment: I just tried this out, it displays 2 as expected. `Furthermore, this is used in a large-ish application, so what other code could be affecting this?` Is it possible that you may have an overload somewhere? Without seeing more code it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code. The size of `baz` is 2. You are possibly overwriting your function somewhere. You can make the function private and Unit test it in isolation.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        foo("abc", "def", "ghi");
    }

    private void foo(string bar, params string[] baz) 
    {
        Debug.Log(baz.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this doesn't exactly answer my question, I accepted it anyways because without it I wouldn't be able to fix the code. Still not certain what the problem was, but changing it to protected made it work as expected. While from a solely coding standpoint, I should continue with this working code, I'm genuinely interested why my fix worked? Regardless, it should've been protected in the first place hehe.